# Реализован способ авторизации на vue через jwt как переделать через cooki (по session id)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

**Реализован способ авторизации на vue через jwt как переделать через cookie (по session id)
.
Может кто-то подсказать туториал?**

Answer (score 1):

Передавать JWT токен по Cookie/Session - недопустимо в данном случае.
Он сохраняется в LocalStorage и при запросах к Back-End'у - происходит валидация с помощью Middleware.

Вот [туториал](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/07/06/vue-vuex-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) по Вашему вопросу.